# word or phrase for 'collective serendipity' or win-win situation

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, idioms

I'm looking for a word or a phrase which describes, a change in situation
having positive effect
or being equally beneficial to both parties involved.
eg. one fears not being able to make it to a scheduled appointment,
and the other party involved calls asking if you could perhaps re-schedule said appointment.
resulting in a mutually beneficial situation out of a potentially bad one.
Kind of like collective serendipity one could say,
I guess somewhat related to 'making the best out of a bad situation'.
Or better yet, thanks to ed86 for the great suggestion; win-win.

So basically, is there another word or phrase for a win-win situation arising
out of a potentially bad one?

many thanks in advance,
K!P

Answer (score 4):

**win win**

adjective

advantageous or satisfactory to all parties involved

> a win–win situation
>
> a win–win deal
>
> a win-win outcome

I've also heard win-win used as a noun in speech.

> "It's **a win win** for everyone."

Comment: That, is deviously simple and clever. I had not even thought about it.
I will add it to my question as it gives me another way to describe the word or phrase I am looking for. (if now this one which kinda perfectly describes)

Comment: I'm glad I can help :)

Comment: And once you have a reasonably close term, consult a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/win-win%20situation).

Answer (score 1):

More formal than "win win", consider **mutually beneficial** (or mutually profitable).